# Copy and fill column from datagridview to another VBNET

Tags: vb.net

I want to copy and divide data from the "range" column in dgv1 to dgv2, I have tried this code but it still doesn't work as I want.

Any suggestions? thanks..
[dgv1 to dgv 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmSPc.png)

```
Dim column As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        Dim newCol As Integer = 0

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows()
            If row.Cells(5).Value.ToString().Equals("I") Then
                DataGridView2.Columns.Insert(newCol, column)
                With column
                    .HeaderText = "R1"
                    .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
                    .ReadOnly = True
                End With
                For rows As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(rows).Cells(5).Value)
                Next
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: *"it still doesn't work as I want"*. What EXACTLY do you want and what EXACTLY does that code do that doesn't meet that need? Explain the problem, not just that there is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using databound `DataTable` objects to manage your data.

Below code is to demonstrate how to fill a `DataTable` and bind it to a DataGridView. Also included a loop to filter your raw data.

This code is just to teach you the syntax, your final code should not be this repetitive! :D

```
Public Class Form1

  'Add two DataGridView controls to form, called DataGridView1 and DataGridView2
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim RawData = New DataTable("RawData")
    RawData.Columns.Add("Range")
    RawData.Rows.Add("I")
    RawData.Rows.Add("II")
    RawData.Rows.Add("III")
    RawData.Rows.Add("IV")
    RawData.Rows.Add("V")
    RawData.Rows.Add("V")
    RawData.Rows.Add("VI")
    RawData.Rows.Add("III")
    RawData.Rows.Add("IV")
    RawData.Rows.Add("V")
    RawData.Rows.Add("VI")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = RawData

    Dim FilteredData = New DataTable("FilteredData")
    FilteredData.Columns.Add("Range I")
    FilteredData.Columns.Add("Range II")
    FilteredData.Columns.Add("Range III")
    FilteredData.Columns.Add("Range IV")
    FilteredData.Columns.Add("Range V")
    FilteredData.Columns.Add("Range VI")
    For i = 0 To RawData.Rows.Count - 1
      Dim RawRow = RawData.Rows(i)
      Dim RawValue = RawRow("Range")
      Dim filteredValues(5) As String
      Select Case RawValue
        Case "I" : filteredValues(0) = "I"
        Case "II" : filteredValues(1) = "II"
        Case "III" : filteredValues(2) = "III"
        Case "IV" : filteredValues(3) = "IV"
        Case "V" : filteredValues(4) = "V"
        Case "VI" : filteredValues(5) = "VI"
        Case Else
          Throw New Exception("Invalid value")
      End Select
      FilteredData.Rows.Add(filteredValues)
    Next
    DataGridView2.DataSource = FilteredData


  End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding!